# how to search with GET method in MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a search with GET Method but I couldnt do the way I need. My html-css code is like below

```
<div class="top_search_form">
    <a class="top_search_btn" href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    <form method="GET" action="/Banyo/Urunler">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="Search" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Search';" />
    </form>
</div>
```

It looks like below

[image]

The user enters some text and hit the enter to do a search. But when I do a search, the URL is like below, which is not the way I need.

```
/Banyo/Urunler?search=asd
```

when the user hits the enter. I want to see the link below

```
/Banyo/Urunler/asd
```

how can I have this URL "/Banyo/Urunler/asd" ? what should I do to have this?

My MapRoute is like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
          "Urunler", // name it!
          "Banyo/Urunler/{Filtre}", // Route name
           new { controller = "Banyo", action = "Urunler", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and I updated my html

```
<form method="GET" action="/Banyo/Urunler">
```

Comment: You'd need to use JavaScript to modify the behavior of the form. The search URL is being provided by your browser which doesn't understand ASP.NET defined routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the parameter name in your action (search in this case) is not defined in your route config, it'll be appended as a query string parameter when doing GET requests.

the default route defines an id parameter so you could use this instead.

Your search field would be renamed to id and your action would have an id parameter as well.

```
public ActionResult Urunler(string id)
{

}
```

Another option would be to use attribue routing (if you are using MVC4 and above).

```
Route("Banyo/Urunler/{search}")]
public ActionResult Urunler(string search)
    {

    }
```

Attribute routing in MVC4 would require you to install the nuget packages yourself ... i think they are added by default in MVC5

Comment: I have "public ActionResult Urunler(string Filtre)" and I updated as you described. but it still shows "/Banyo/Urunler?Filtre=asd"

Comment: Browsers only submit form values in the query string of a URL. That means anything the user types will go after the `?` in the URL. To make the user-data go in the pathname (before the query string and after the domain), you'd need to use JavaScript. It has nothing to do with how the server is configured.

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ move the new route to the top of the route definitions .. it should be above the default route since they are evaluated from top to bottom .. if the default route is encountered first it is used instead.

Comment: @Pluto the form gets submitted and the server renders the Urunler action .. so yes the server is involved ..

Comment: Except that's not what the question is about at all. It's about the wrong link being sent to the server, a link generated from a form *on a browser*.

Comment: @Pluto the link isn't wrong (in this context) .. the way the model binder works .. it checks query string, form values etc to populate the action parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In the form, add JavaScript to the `onsubmit` attribute. For example...

```
<form onsubmit="location.assign(this.action+'/'+this.search.value);return false" action="/Banyo/Urunler">
```

This browses the `<input>` tag's value appended to the URL provided by the form. `this.search` provides access to the `<input>` element with the name of "search".